# Power Comes into Light fixture from Panel, connected to switch how to wire always on outlet in

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, light-fixture

In my workshop I want to wire in some outlets. The power comes into the room into a light then is branched to other lights and a switch in the room to control said lights. I know how to hook up the outlet if I want to make it switched. How would I go about wiring it up unswitched? Would I tap off the hot in the light fixture?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install a receptacle that is not switch it must come from a location which has a source conductor, neutral and ground. If the power source is coming into a light fixture first then that would be the place to tap it. However if the switch was installed under the new NEC requirements, then it should also have a neutral and you can tap the conductors from there. Look to your feed going to the switch and see if it contains 4 conductors a source, switch leg, neutral and ground. I not you can also replace the feed from the light fixture to the switch with the correct cable.

Good luck